# how to make Dialog flow Webhook to call API deployed in AWS?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am making a boot using DialogFlow, So far, I have tried "user says","entities" and "responses" using DialogFlow web. These are seems easy.

I did not see any reason for programming until I wanted to inject data provided by our web API, which is deployed in AWS, in the bot's replies.

Is it possible? could any one direct me to an example?

I am new to DialogFlow, hint me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check https://github.com/dialogflow for flask and node js sample weather web hook implementation